# How to push images to private registry pod with nerdctl

Tags: container-registry, nerdctl

I have created 3 node k8s cluster as show below with containerd as runtime using [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)
Note: No docker binary is running on nodes.

```
get no -o wide
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                               KERNEL-VERSION                 CONTAINER-RUNTIME
node11   Ready    control-plane,worker   2d17h   v1.26.3   a.b.c.x   <none>        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)   4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64   containerd://1.7.0
node12   Ready    control-plane,worker   2d17h   v1.26.3   a.b.c.y    <none>        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)   4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64   containerd://1.7.0
node13   Ready    control-plane,worker   2d17h   v1.26.3   a.b.c.z    <none>        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)   4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64   containerd://1.7.0
```

As per documentation, provide flag `registry_enabled: true` and I can see registry pod as below'

```
kubectl get po -n kube-system -o wide | grep registry
registry-l5ndk                             1/1     Running   0               3h18m   10.233.88.135   node12   <none>           <none>
```

Can anyone guide how i can push images to this registry?

I am expecting that i should be able to push my application images using nerdctl push command

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the port for registry service

   export NODEPORT=$(kubectl get svc -n kube-system registry -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}');

   echo ${NODEPORT}

   export REGNODE=node1 # prefer controller

then

1. tag image:

   nerdctl tag nginx:1.23.2-alpine    ${REGNODE}:${NODEPORT}//nginx:1.23.2-alpine
2. push image to registry:

   nerdctl push ${REGNODE}:${NODEPORT}/nginx:1.23.2-alpine
3. pull image from registry:

   nerdctl pull ${REGNODE}:${NODEPORT}/nginx:1.23.2-alpine